# Chose what Places of Interest should show up on my map

Tags: mapbox

I am trying to customize my map so that all commercial places of interest do not show up. I am trying to do this with the control density by category. It looks like it is not the right place as certain restaurants, hotels and supermarkets are still visible. (see screenshot)